# truncate folder path to extract only part of it

Tags: python

Hi I have the following code. It does what I want, but if I want the '\myserv\zip\20131114' to be a variable how could I update my code?

```
folderName=r'\\myserv\zip\20131114'
folderName.replace('\\', '/')
dayDate= folderName[-8:]
print dayDate
>>>20131114
```

I have a global string variable in my script where folderName will change. How can i add the 'r' to my folderName string. If I do not add the r' I think it converts "\201" to a special character.

```
folderName = '\\myserv\zip\20131114'
x = 'r' + folderName
print x

>>>>zipﾁ31114
```

Thank you

Comment: How is it not a variable?

Comment: Explain more your problem

Comment: How can i add the r' to my folderName string. If I do not add the r' I think it converts "\201" to a special character.

Comment: You need to escape your forward-slashes if you don't use the `r` keyword.

Comment: @Keikoku: Backward slashes ;)

Comment: You don't add an `r` to the string in your program. You might write a folder path in the source code with a leading `r` to make it a raw string, but for Python it's just a normal string. If you have a line with `folderName = '\\myserv\zip\20131114'`it's just wrong.

Comment: @jazzpi I always mix up whether I look at the top of the slash or the bottom...

Comment: @Matthias Ok thank you. I'll try and adjust the previous code to not have that variable

Comment: Like the rest already said: escape the backward slashes:
`foldername = '\\myserv\\zip\\20131114'` will print `\myserv\zip\20131114`.

Answer (score -1):

You want to add an `r'` to the front of your string and get rid of the `\201` misinterpretation?

Try:

```
folderName = '\\myserv\\zip\\20131114'
x = 'r\'' + folderName
print x
```

**Output:**

```
r'\myserv\zip\20131114
```

Fix your slashes (the strings need to be escaped with `\`). Same with the `'` in `r'`.

Comment: No. He wants to add the `r` keyword.

Comment: He wants to add it to the front of the string?

Comment: It looks like he wants to convert the string to a raw string, which isn't possible (AFAIK), since raw strings are just a way to tell the python interpreter to read `\` literally and not as beginning of an escape sequence.

Comment: Oh... Well, I guess he agrees with you, because it appears he down-voted my answer.

Comment: No that was not me who did that. I can probably do a workaround like dayDate= "201" + folderName[-5:]. I'll just have to update it in 6 years if we are still using it.

Comment: I thought he just wanted to put an 'r' in front of it for whatever reason, and fix his '\201' problem.